# Is it possible to make Angular ReactiveForm ValidatorFn which set error for a few seconds?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm trying to write `ValidatorFn` to check does the form's control have duplicates.

I have written a validator to check it and return an error, but is it possible to remove this error after a few seconds by this validator? *I know how to make it from a component, but I want to write it once and reuse for all controls with this validator*

```js
export function tagDuplicates(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (!(control.dirty || control.touched) || !control.value) {
      return null;
    } else {
      const values = [...control.value].map(reduceString);

      if (values.some((el: string, index: number) => values.indexOf(el) !== index)) {
        control.value.pop();

        return { duplicate: `Item already added` };
      }

      return null;
    }
  };
}

function reduceString(str: string): string {
  return str.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/[ ,.]/g, '');
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, no, not possible.

Comment: You can do by some Angular animation to when error message comes to screen, will be hided after few seconds, btw in your case what you want to happen if I enter the duplicate for the second time?

Comment: @LppEdd, remember: imposible is nothing :)

Comment: @Reza the same behavior. _I forgot to remove the last added duplicate, fixed it in question code_

Comment: I re-write my answer, it's only use setErrors(null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you has the control, so you can using a timer of Rxjs use setErrors(null)

```
import {timer} from 'rxjs'
...
if (values.some((el: string, index: number) => values.indexOf(el) !== index)) {

    timer(5000).subscribe(res=>{
        control.setErrors(null)
     })
     return { duplicate: `Item already added` };
 }
```

You can see a example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll use `delete control.errors.duplicate` instead of `control.setErrors(null)`, because of control could have another validators and errors